# Certificate ending on 28/06/21 how to update it?

Tags: ios, date, certificate, period, mitmproxy

I'm using mitm on ios to test some app, but since yesterday I can't log in any website, or even use google.
It seems that the certificate has expired on the 28/06.
I've tried to download a new one on mitm.it, but it's already expired.
Do someone have any idea how i can bypass that ?

[image: pic of oudated certificate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force mitmproxy to generate a totally new root CA certificate by simply deleting the old one.

Mitmproxy stores the root CA certificate and it's key in the directory `~/.mitmproxy` (mitmproxy config directory in your home directory on the computer running mitmproxy).

If you rename or delete that directory and restart mitmproxy a new root-CA certificate will be generated.

Then you can install this new certificate as usual via `http://mitm.it`